# java Index 5 out of bounds for length 5 error while doing while loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to switch every odd index character with the nearest even index character to it in a string.

```java
public class A3_Q1 {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the messgae you want to be coded: ");
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg = in.nextLine();
        
        in.close();
        
        msg = msg.trim();
        char msg1[] =  msg.toCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        
        while (index<msg.length()) {
            msg1[index] = msg1[++index];
            index++;
        }
    
        System.out.print(msg1); 
    }

}
```

I tried searching and asking more experienced friends what's wrong but we don't know bare with us all compsci freshmen

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different programming languages. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Hi& welcome! `msg1[index] = msg1[++index];index++;` has same meaning/effect as: `msg1[index] = msg1[index];
            index=index+2;` (..is probably wrong;)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if index is `msg.length() -1`? You will be out-of-range.

So you should check two condition in your loop.

1. index is odd or even
2. index and `index + 1` is not out-of-bound `msg.length`.

Answer (score 0):

`++index` increments the index first before using the value.
`index++` uses the value first before incrementing.
That means each iteration increments `index` by 2.
If `msg` has an odd length (your example 5) and `index = 4` you enter the loop.
`[++index]` is evaluated to `[5]` and you get the exception.

So you have to ignore the last character for odd lenths with `while (index<msg.length() - 1)`

Answer (score -1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    // Best practice: one instruction per one line
    System.out.print("Enter the message you want to be coded: ");

    // When using System.in you should not close the Scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = scan.nextLine().trim();
    // Best practice: move encoding logic to the separate method
    String convertedMessage = convert(message);
    System.out.println(convertedMessage);
}

public static String convert(String str) {
    // String is immutable, so we have to use StringBuilder to build a new string
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    // does not matter what to use, I prefer for...loop
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // do not forget to check case for the last index
        if (i == str.length() - 1 || i % 2 != 0)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));
        else
            // here we have odd and not last index (just use the next one)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i + 1));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Demo**

```
Enter the message you want to be coded: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bbddffhhjjllnnpprrttvvxxzz
```

Answer (score -1):

It will out of bounds because:

```
while (index<msg.length()) {
            msg1[index] = msg1[++index];
            index++;
        }
```

java index start with 0. So if the lengh is 5 it will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
msg1[index] = msg1[++index];
```

On this line with index 4 you will out of bounds because 4+1 is 5.
you need to add something like this

```
if(++index<msg.length())
```

Comment: you increment `index` with `if(++index<msg.length())` so you have to remove `++` in `msg[++index]`